# Inner.HTML shown of result flicker

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

```
function BMI(){
var h = document.getElementById('height').value;
var w = document.getElementById('weight').value;

  var bmi= w/(h/100*h/100);
  var bmi2 = (bmi.toFixed(2));

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " your BMI is " + bmi2;

}
```

why the output of "result" is flickering

Comment: Are you calling BMI() function multiple times? it may be updating the id result element multiple times

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? You should at least share a full working example

Comment: html is <p id="result"></p>          //is it because I use onClick ="BMI()"in html ?

Answer (score -2):

You should convert the String into Number because in Javascript when you try to get the value from an input it is in String by default. And use template literals instead of concatenating the Strings.

```
function BMI(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var h = Number(document.getElementById('height').value);
  var w = Number(document.getElementById('weight').value);

  var bmi= w/(h/100*h/100);
  var bmi2 = (bmi.toFixed(2));

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = `Your BMI is ${bmi2}`;

}
```

Comment: thx for mention but that is not resolving the problem of flickering ..

Comment: Are you adding the onClick event in submit type button ?